# The One With the Brahmin Heckler

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras

Does there exist such a sutta in which a brahmin pays a visit to the Buddha at his dwelling at Jeta's Grove with the sole intent to heckle, only to be met with silence and then brought to his senses when he asks, "Why aren't you delivering your sermon? I would like to hear it." The Buddha tells him that only anger and rage are in his mind and that if he can distance himself from all the anguish, hurt, and jealousy, he will deliver a sermon to him. The brahmin sees that the Buddha saw through him and repents.

This is a story from [the fourth book](https://blog.naver.com/buddhafind/220343842393) of the Korean version of the Saṃyutta Nikāya called 별역잡아함경. From what I gather, the suttas do not correspond one-for-one with the Saṃyutta Nikāya, and for the life of me, I cannot find the above story in any English version available online. Does such a story exist in the Saṃyutta Nikāya or anywhere else in the Pāli Canon, for that matter? Or is it only in the Korean edition for some reason? If it helps, the brahmin's name is 반려(返淚), but of course it's impossible to figure out what the original Pāli name is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From SN 7.16 - Paccanīka Sutta:

> At S›vatthı. Now on that occasion a brahmin named Paccanıkas›ta, Relisher of Contradiction, was residing at S›vatthı. Then it occurred to the brahmin Paccanıkas›ta: “Let me approach the ascetic Gotama and contradict whatever he says.” Now on that occasion the Blessed One was walking back and forth in the open. Then the brahmin Paccanıkas›ta approached the Blessed One and said to him while he was walking back and forth: “Speak Dhamma, ascetic!”

> [The Blessed One:]
> 693 “Well-spoken counsel is hard to understand By one who relishes contradiction, By one with a corrupt mind <386> Who is engrossed in aggression.
> 694 “But if one has removed aggression And the distrust of one’s heart, If one has cast away aversion, One can understand well-spoken counsel.”

> When this was said, the brahmin Paccanıkas›ta said to the Blessed One: “Magnificent, Master Gotama! Magnificent, Master Gotama!… Let Master Gotama remember me as a lay follower who from today has gone for refuge for life.”

Comment: From suttacentral: [SN 7.16](https://suttacentral.net/sn7.16/en/sujato) translated by Ven. Sujato

Comment: Actually I was using Ven. Bodhi's version, which's not available on suttacentral.net, hence no hyperlink provided. But Sujato's version is not too bad, so thanks for pointing to his link.

Comment: Thank you so much. The Korean version is quite different, and that's curious, but that is a research topic for another day.

Comment: Ur welcome. Yeah, words might vary, but the gist is pretty much  the same. _/\\_